Bluetooth button in Ubuntu 23.10 doesn't work
I tried several methods to activate the Bluetooth on my laptop (Packard Bell). However, the Bluetooth settings button doesn't work and does not turn on.
Any suggestions to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.
You find the image attached for further details.
Bluetooth button

23.10 reached EOL July 2024 and in now off topic

Ubuntu 23.10 (along with all flavors) is End-of-Life and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/07/17/ubuntu-23-10-mantic-minotaur-reached-end-of-life-on-july-11-2024/   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Don't forget by using an EOL release; your software packages are all stale and not getting security fixes UNLESS you're backporting those fixes yourself; so keep yourself offline unless you're doing the work to manually apply security fixes (ie. backporting them from supported release patches)
